use didSet with Swift dictionary
Is there a way to use didSet property observer to observe if a particular key in a dictionary is set to a new value?
For example:
enum PlayerStats: String, Codable  {
    case maxHealthPoint
    case maxActionPoint
    case HP
    case AP
    case movementSpeed
    case attackSpeed
}

 var stats = [PlayerStats: Float]()

Based on above code, is there a way to let didSet get called only when attackSpeed is set to a new value?
If this is a wrong approach what can I do to achieve my goal?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Why use a dictionary here? Why not just write 6 different properties?

You cannot directly handle didSet or willSet in this scenario. However, you may want to try this approach by wrapping stats into a Player model then customize the setter logic. Something like:
struct Player {
    private var _stats: [PlayerStats: Float] = [:]

    var stats: [PlayerStats: Float] {
        get {
            return _stats
        } set {
            for (key, value) in newValue where key == .attackSpeed {
                _stats[.attackSpeed] = value
            }
        }
    }
}

This is how you will use it:
var player = Player()
player.stats[.HP] = 10 //Will not update the underlying _stats
player.stats[.attackSpeed] = 100 //Only update .attackSpeed to the underlying _stats


Thank you sonle. Your answer enlighten me.  for (key, value) in newValue where key == .attackSpeed {...} is what I was looking for. I got it to work with didSet observer.

I don’t understand this answer, why have a dictionary where you can only set/update one property? Or am I missing something?

I suppose it made no sense in the code above. However, I had no idea what OP was going through either, so I only focused on the part use didSet property observer . @JoakimDanielson

What's the point of the for statement. Why not just write _stats[.attackSpeed] = newValue[.attackSpeed]?
